# download mail attachments service

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, office-interop

I have made a console application in c# that can go to an outlook mail , to a specific folder and check for new incoming mails, if the mail has an attachment - it will save it on a folder.
The application works , even with the EXE i have made from the compilation.
The issue is that i want this app will run every 5 minutes.
Now, i can use a Loop in the app but this is not my desire that the app will be running 24/7,
That is why i have made a task shceduler that will call the app every 5 minutes.
But i have figured that office apps does not run well on service / scheduler.
The app creates 2 folders - the first is to store the attachments, and the second if to create/update file that hold the processed mail Ids so on the next run it will not process them.
When i run the exe file manually it downloads the attachments and also make the file with records of mail ids that were processed.
When the scheduler run the exe - its only create the folders, but does not make the "log" file, and also does not download the attachments.
when i try to make another action that will save a log to another txt file in case there was an error  - it did show me this error :

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error  80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

I hope this is detailed enough,
Is there a way to accomplish my request (download attachments from new mails )?